# Could not fetch campaign budget limit - Facebook ad group create

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

After trying to create **ad group** on **facebook Ads API**, I am facing the problem with error message:

> Could not fetch campaign budget limit

**Campaign is created correctly**, and set budget is fine. Ad groups do not have budget to set, so this error is even stranger.

The same error was happening before, in 1/50 campaigns, but it always happens once, next time you try to create same ad group it works fine.

At the moment this problem repeats constatly for the campaign.

Kind regards,
Nikola

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is being tracked at https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/202750126586681/